# How implement the function of `case` in DDL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `order`. Its **DDL** is listed below

```
create table "order"
(
    id                      serial primary key,
    quantity                integer      not null,
    estimated_delivery_date date         not null,
    lodgement_date          date check ( lodgement_date > '2022-03-02' ),
    product_model           varchar(128) not null,
    sales_id                integer      not null,
    contract_number         varchar(10)  not null
);
```

I want to make the `lodgement_date` attribute to be `null` if it is later than `2022-03-02` when inserting a new row. How can I achieve this function in **DDL**.

Comment: What's the certain condition? Is it a value in another table? Or some other thing that you want to define at the start of the script? This rings some alarm bells. Are you certain you are approching this the right way? Are you provisioning lots of databases that may or may not have the same schema? Perhaps you could add some background information.

Comment: You cannot do what you are wanting.  DDL tells the DB what is the *data type* the values must be, in the case of `lodgement_date`  a  *date* but it can be any [date within defined range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-datetime.html). The check constraint then places a restriction on that range. However, violating either will not alter the value, it throws an exception. Setting values are strictly DML. You will need a trigger to alter the column's value to null when outside the restricted limit.

Comment: A before-insert trigger is what you need and not a check constraint as @Belayer said. And btw there is an extra comma in your DDL.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can't do it in the creation of the table. It is gonna be a constraint.

Example:

```
CONSTRAINT check_lodgement_date
CHECK (lodgement_date > '2022-03-02')
```